# Retrieve localStorage data using Flask

Tags: javascript, flask, local-storage

I am working on a project that requires user login/logout. I have managed to pass data and store them in the localStorage. However, I cannot find the easiest way to integrate Flask with the localStorage file without using jQuery. I would love to have some suggestions from people who have already tried this out before. Here are my Python script and JavaScript code

Here is the Python Flask script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    # DO SOMETHING TO AUTHENTICATE USER AND GENERATE TOKEN
    return render_template("base.html", token="token")

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    # RETRIEVE TOKEN FROM LOCAL STORAGE
    return "Success"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the HTML + JavaScript simplify code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Hello </h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // STORE TOKEN INTO LOCALSTORAGE
      localStorage.setItem("token", "{{token}}");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check out [Flask Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for user authentication. It generates session cookies and server-side user IDs on its own.

Comment: Hello @JordanMann. Thank you for your suggestion. However, for this project, I am required to manually generate JWT for authentication. The way I am approaching is to store that JWT into the LocalStorage.

Comment: Get and set cookies instead of using localStorage. These are sent in requests to the server, meaning that you can verify a user. [Here's an example.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_cookies.htm)

Comment: @JordanMann cookies have a limit of 4KB which will very likely be hit sometime by someone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`localStorage` lives on the browser side of things. The server can't access it directly.

You'll need to send the token from the client to the server when the user presses the `logout` button in your app.

```js
document.getElementById('logout').onclick = function logout() {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token')

    // use your favourite AJAX lib to send the token to the server as e.g. JSON

    // redirect user to e.g. landing page of app if logout successul, show error otherwise
}
```

Your view will receive the token and do something useful with it.

```py
@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    token = request.get_json()['token']

    # log the user out

    return jsonify({'status':'success'})
```